# Pyftpsync works only without TLS

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, ftplib, ftps

Hi I'm using pyftpsync in order to upload new images (downloaded every day) in a online store skipping the existing ones.

From the author site I'm using this code (with my personal data of course):

```
from ftpsync.targets import FsTarget
from ftpsync.ftp_target import   FtpTarget
from ftpsync.synchronizers import UploadSynchronizer

local = FsTarget("~/temp")
user ="joe" 
passwd = "secret" 
remote = FtpTarget("/temp", "example.com", username=user, password=passwd) 
opts= {"force": False, "delete_unmatched": True, "verbose": 3, "dry_run" : False} 
s = UploadSynchronizer(local, remote, opts,tls=True)
s.run()
```

This work for me correctly only if I delete the tls option, otherwise I obtain this error while connecting to my server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sync.py", line 25, in <module>
s.run()
File "/media/luca/1E9C3E629C3E349D/luca/Documenti/attività/Cataloghi2/ftpsync/synchronizers.py", line 139, in run
res = self._sync_dir()
File "/media/luca/1E9C3E629C3E349D/luca/Documenti/attività/Cataloghi2/ftpsync/synchronizers.py", line 416, in _sync_dir
remote_entries = self.remote.get_dir()
File "/media/luca/1E9C3E629C3E349D/luca/Documenti/attività/Cataloghi2/ftpsync/ftp_target.py", line 310, in get_dir
self.ftp.retrlines("MLSD", _addline)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 466, in retrlines
resp = self.sendcmd('TYPE A')
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 272, in sendcmd
return self.getresp()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 235, in getresp
resp = self.getmultiline()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 221, in getmultiline
line = self.getline()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 209, in getline
raise EOFError
EOFError
Could not remove lock file: Underlying socket connection gone (_ssl.c:1570)
Exception ignored in: <bound method FtpTarget.__del__ of <ftpsync.ftp_target.FtpTarget object at 0x7fe397ae7710>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/luca/1E9C3E629C3E349D/luca/Documenti/attività/Cataloghi2/ftpsync/targets.py", line 70, in __del__
File "/media/luca/1E9C3E629C3E349D/luca/Documenti/attività/Cataloghi2/ftpsync/ftp_target.py", line 153, in close
File "/media/luca/1E9C3E629C3E349D/luca/Documenti/attività/Cataloghi2/ftpsync/ftp_target.py", line 187, in _unlock
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 613, in delete
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 271, in sendcmd
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 198, in putcmd
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 193, in putline
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 720, in sendall
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 681, in send
ssl.SSLError: Underlying socket connection gone (_ssl.c:1570)
```

It's obviously a problem related to the encryption, but I don't know how to fix it.